# I want to direct the object to the opposite side where I pulled the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to direct the object to the opposite side where I swiped the screen.
The object is already on the scene.I want to edit only the y coordinate.

For example...

Suppose the user swipes Android's screen from the top down.
Then, the object looks at the back side,
When the user swipes the screen of Android from left to right,
That object looks to the left.

I have technology to change the direction of objects using joystick in Unity official StandardAssets.

Anybody answer please.

Comment: You mean `looks` or `locks`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: exactly ;) what do you mean by `the object looks at the back side` or `object looks to the left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to detect a direction of the swipe. Then, assign scale or rotation of the object respectively to the direction.

To do the swipe direction calculation, you can look for some solution on the Asset Store.
Or you can implement it on your own:

1) Make a fullscreen touch area (collider). Attach a MonoBehaviour script that implements `IPointerDownHandler` and `IPointerUpHandler` interfaces to it.

2) Remember touch position of the PointerDown event.

3) In the PointerUp event handler do the calculation of direction:

```
    var distance = pointerUpPosition - pointerDownPosition;

    if (distance.y > distance.x) // vertical
    {
       theObject.transform.localScale *= Vector3.up * (pointerUpPosition.y > pointerDownPosition.y ? -1 : 1);
    }
    else
    {
       theObject.transform.localScale *= Vector3.right * (pointerUpPosition.x > pointerDownPosition.x ? -1 : 1);
    }
```

This solution does not include edge cases, f.i. straight diagonal swipes. Also it uses scale for orienting the object and will rotate it every swipe.

You can achieve similar implementation with the Unity's UI event system as well. However, events will be different there.